# how to create batch file in system folder using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was wondering how I would be able to create a batch file in the startup folder using a batch file. I can get the file to create in common places on my disk(desktop, documents) but I can not get it to create in the startup folder. Can I give the child batch file admin permissions in order to be copied or created to the startup folder?

Comment: Yes, maybe you could give admin permission to process(es).

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you really trying to accomplish? More likely than not, your problem can be solved using the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try for this code :

```bat
@echo off
Set "Startup_Folder=%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
(
    echo @echo off
    echo echo Hello this is a test
    echo pause
) >"%Startup_Folder%\test.bat"
pause
```